# Changing the Wording Sender Sees in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi, french

I have changed the individual private messages in Docusign to French.  I want to update the English that shows:  "Please review the documents below" "FINISH" button and "OTHER ACTIONS" and "START" "NEXT" tagging to French language as well.  I have checked admin settings to no avail.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you using the API? or via the web UI? you can do it either way, just trying to figure out what answer to give you....

Answer (score 0):

When you send an envelope, and go to the bottom of the recipients page under Message All Recipients you'll find a checkbox:
"Custom email and language for each recipient"
Once you check it, you will get a new drop-down next to each recipient where you can select the specific language you wish this recipient will see.

More information can be found here - https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-recipient-language